# timezone format warning with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i use momentJS to format time from server to something similar to "2 hours ago". Server time zone is UTC while my timezone is UTC + 8 so i use the following code to make it:

```
  formatTime(date, timezone) {    
    let serverTime  = moment.utc(date + " " + timezone, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").toDate();
    return(moment(serverTime.toString()).fromNow());
  }

   console.log(formatTime('2019-08-06 07:48:00','UTC'));
```

'2019-08-06 07:48:00' and 'UTC' are fetch data from server. The output is correct but i have a warning message from momentJS: "**Deprecation warning**: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release."

Comment: That means you should not use that format but rather an ISO compliant format, like a generic ISO string. The real meaning of that alert is that, really, the format you provided **may lead to undesired behaviors across browser**.

Comment: The string you're passing to moment.js does not match the format string you're supplying. You need to add the timezone (whatever it is) to the parse format. `date + " " + timezone` probably requires a parse format like "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ" (assuming +0800, use Z for +08:00).